# input Csv models.FileField into pandas object

Tags: python, django, csv

I have model Field instance.

```
myCsv =  myFile.objects.get(id=1) // myCsv.document is models.FileField
```

and want to put this in pandas.

```
df = pd.read_csv(thred.document.read())
```

`OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type`

How can I put the cev file to pandas object??

Comment: Try `df = pd.read_csv(thred.document)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can try like this:

```
thred =  myFile.objects.get(id=1)
df = pd.read_csv(thred.document.path)
```

More information regarding path can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/#using-files-in-models) on how to manage files in `FileField`(or `ImageField`).

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(myCsv.document.path())` has error below
`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: I am not calling `path()` here in this answer. It is just `path`.

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'/media/documents/threshold_1_eTqYWZf.csv' does not exist: b'/media/documents/threshold_1_eTqYWZf.csv'`

Comment: ALmost there.... acturely there is a file in `/media/documents/threshold_1_eTqYWZf.csv'...but can't open..`  `b'` is related???

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. Please make sure if the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what worked for me.
thred - django model's object.
document - Filefield

```
import pandas as pd
csv_reader = pd.read_csv(thred.document.open().url)
```